# What will be running time of this code? Is it n log n or n?

Tags: time-complexity

I have written this code to find pow(a,n) using divide and conquer method. I am not sure about the big oh complexity of this code. Is it n or nlog n?

```
pow(a,n)
{
  if n->1 return a
  i<-floor(n/2)
  j<-ceil(n/2)
  return pow(a,i) * pow(a,j)
}
```

Also what will be complexity of the combining step which is multiplication in this case? is it 1 or n?

Answer (score 0):

Approximately O(n) since each call to `pow(a,n)` leads to ~2 calls to `pow(a,n/2)`.

Comment: doesn't that mean it is dividing problems into n/2, meaning log n levels and at each level work is n/2. which makes it nlogn?

Comment: Consider the number of calls when you have p(1,8): p(1,4)*p(1,4) then p(1,2)*p(1,2)*p(1,2)*p(1,2) then p(1,1)*p(1,1)*p(1,1)*p(1,1)*p(1,1)*p(1,1)*p(1,1)*p(1,1).  The total number of invocations is 1+2+4+8 = 15.

Comment: The work at each level isn't n/2 since you're only doing O(1) work per call.